# How to update records with multiple tables linked by a foreign key using XQuery (or OPENXML) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml, xquery-sql

I have T-SQL code like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT  CONVERT(xml, BulkColumn, 2) FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk 'C:\test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) [blah])

-- Data for Table 1
SELECT
    ES.value('id-number[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') IDNumber,
    ES.value('name[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') Name,
    ES.value('date[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') Date,
    ES.value('test[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') Test,
    ES.value('testing[1]', 'VARCHAR(511)') Testing,
    ES.value('testingest[1]', 'VARCHAR(5)') Testingest
FROM @xml.nodes('xmlnodes/path') AS EfficiencyStatement(ES)

-- Data for Table 2
SELECT
    U.value('fork[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') Fork,
    U.value('spoon[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') Spoon,
    U.value('spork[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') Spork,
FROM @xml.nodes('xmlnodes/path/nextpath') AS Utensils(U)
```

Now, I've tried what I normally use, and other variants, such as:

```
AS XML ON xml.[id-number] = [table1].[id-number]
```

For the record, `id-number` is unique across the entire document. It can never occur again.

This is good for grabbing the data from my XML file, but there's zero referential integrity. How do I make sure that Table 2 (and up) maintains referential integrity when inserting?

**This should be a much better explanation**:

1. I want to load XML values from a file. For `INSERT`, I have no trouble using `OPENXML` and binding it based on the id-number using `AS XML ON xml.[id-number] = [table1].[id-number]` at the end.
2. I want to update the database record (with all linked tables and their columns) using `UPDATE`, `MERGE`, or something -- anything! To do this, I believe I need to find a way to maintain referential integrity based on the `Foreign_ID` value present in each table. There are dozens of tables which are all linked via `Foreign_ID`, so how do I update all of these?

### Table Example

```
  Table #1
+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Primary_Key | ID_Number |    Name   |    Date    |   Test  |  Testing  | Testingest |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------|
|   70001     |   12345   |   Tom     |  01/21/14  |   Hi    |    Yep    | Of course! |
|   70002     |   12346   |   Dick    |  02/22/14  |   Bye   |    No     | Never!     |
|   70003     |   12347   |   Harry   |  03/23/14  |   Sup   |    Dunno  | Same.      |
+----^--------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
     |
     |-----------------|
                       |    
  Table #2             | Linked to primary key in the first table. 
+-------------+--------v--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Primary_Key |    Foreign_ID   |     Fork    |    Spoon    |    Spork   | 
+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|   0001      |     70001       |     Yes     |     No      |     No     |
|   0002      |     70002       |     No      |     Yes     |     No     |
|   0003      |     70003       |     No      |     No      |     Yes    |
+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

After that is inserted, I need to be able to `UPDATE` the tables and columns from the XML files. After much research, I can't figure out how to update the values of every table linked by `Foreign_ID` *while* maintaining referential integrity. This means I am inserting the wrong data in the other tables.

I want the correct data updated. To update it correctly, I need to ensure that XQuery is matching the right data. Some tables have multiple fields for one particular Foreign_ID.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT  CONVERT(xml, BulkColumn, 2) FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk 'C:\test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) [blah])

-- Data for Table 1
SELECT
    ES.value('id-number[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') IDNumber,
    ES.value('name[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') Name,
    ES.value('date[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') Date,
    ES.value('test[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') Test,
    ES.value('testing[1]', 'VARCHAR(511)') Testing,
    ES.value('testingest[1]', 'VARCHAR(5)') Testingest
INTO #TempTable
FROM @xml.nodes('xmlnodes/path') AS EfficiencyStatement(ES)


-- @Serial Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
SET @IDNumber = (SELECT SerialNumber from #TempTable)


SET @Foreign_ID = (SELECT [Foreign_ID] from [table] WHERE [id-number] = @IDNumber)


MERGE dbo.[table1] AS CF
USING (SELECT IDNumber, Name, Date, Test, Testing, Testingest FROM #TempTable) AS src
ON CF.[id-number] = src.IDNumber
-- ID-Number is unique, and is used to setup the initial referential integrity. Foreign_ID does not exist in the XML files, so we are not matching on that.

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET
   CF.[id-number] = src.IDNumber
   -- and so on...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
-- Insert statements here
GO
```

This works for the first table. It does not maintain integrity when updating the other tables via `Foreign_ID`. Note that `SET @Serial` has an error, but when I set it to anything else, it will update properly.

Comment: Check this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8wa0tw7(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I already have, and that will not solve my problem. These are static XML files which we aren't allowed to modify, and they aren't XSD.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what you are asking here, but if you cannot use the suggested article to enforce references in your XML, there is not really a post-op way for you to do it just in XML.

For Table2+ you can do EXISTS checks against TABLE 1 and process accordingly that way (see [Referential integrity issue with Untyped XML in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014728/referential-integrity-issue-with-untyped-xml-in-tsql) for example)

The only other way that I can think of is to create "real" tables that represent your schema for table 1, table 2...tableN that have the relevant FKs and insert into them.

Comment: I have updated the question to help you better understand it.

Comment: Still having troubles.  What do you mean "it does not maintain integrity with updating the other tables"?  It is putting adding rows that should not be in there?

How does your data know which table needs to be updated/matched via the Foreign_ID value?

Comment: Like this: I load all the XML into a temporary table. I then insert it, but I don't know which order it's in. It doesn't gather everything, does it? I'm only getting 1 result for certain when sometimes I should be getting 2 or more. Here's an example: one table has multiple results for one field, but when I select those results, they are sorted out of order... meaning it will bring up everything in that table, but there's no ordering. I need to make it match a Foreign_ID id, so I can select by that ID to get the accompanying records.

Comment: The data knows which table needs to be updated matched when the Foreign_ID value is the same. The Foreign_ID value is set from the INSERT statement, and is based on the unique [id-number] present in each XML node. There could be one parent node in each root, or 400,000. I want to represent a single node and loop through them, I guess. Something like `foreach (string[] parent in XmlNode) { Insert Record }`

Comment: I've finally figured it out, and I will be posting the answer once I finish writing the rest of it.